# MySQL Workbench Trigger Show Text and Insert Corrected Version

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I'm new to MySQL, I googled and chatGPT'ed but couldn't come up with a solution. I have been reading stack overflow for a few years now but I almost never ask anything, I would appreciate your feedback on how to improve my questions as well.

I want to create a trigger that checks the weight_t value and sets it to 0 if negative or to a max value if above that value and then inserts it to the table. It should also show a message.
My attempts either showed the error message in the response and inserted nothing or set the entered value to  the corrected value and inserted it without showing any message in the console or log files.

My final code is below, which only raises the message(as intended) but inserts nothing (Error Code: 1644. Weight value too low! Changing to 0)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_before_insert_scw
BEFORE INSERT ON supply_chain_waste
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.weight_t < 0 THEN
        SET NEW.weight_t = 0;
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Weight value too low! Changing to 0';
    END IF;
    IF NEW.weight_t > 19111000 THEN
        SET NEW.weight_t = 19111000;
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Weight value too high! Changing to 19111000';
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Following is the insert statement I use and it works fine otherwise:

```
insert into supply_chain_waste(country_name, year, weight_t) values ('Germany', 1948, -1);
```

Comment: FYI, using ChatGPT to learn things new to you is really a bad habit you should avoid forming, because ChatGPT is known to "hallucinate" and give you answers that are fictional. It's up to you to vet the responses from ChatGPT. But if it's a topic you don't already know, then by definition you can't distinguish fictional responses from factual responses. Use ChatGPT as a super-autocomplete for things you already understand well, but don't use it as a tutor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `SIGNAL` in a trigger, it cancels the action that spawned the trigger. Just like any other error caused by the trigger or by the INSERT. For example if you try to assign NULL to a non-NULL column, the INSERT fails; none of the columns on that row are inserted.

This means you can't use `SIGNAL` to return a message and also have the INSERT succeed with modified values.

The closest thing you could do is set a user-defined variable with the "message." This variable retains its value after the INSERT is complete.

For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_before_insert_scw
BEFORE INSERT ON supply_chain_waste
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.weight_t < 0 THEN
        SET NEW.weight_t = 0;
        SET @advisory_message = 'Weight value too low! Changing to 0';
    END IF;
    IF NEW.weight_t > 19111000 THEN
        SET NEW.weight_t = 19111000;
        SET @advisory_message = 'Weight value too high! Changing to 19111000';
    END IF;
END
```

It would be your responsibility to check that user-defined variable after you perform the INSERT.

Also if you do a multi-row insert, things get more complex. Would you need to know which row(s) needed to be modified? Given that the trigger executes once for each row, how do you want to accumulate the message? Etc. It takes some thought.

Comment: Regrettably there isn't a way to display a normal message in a trigger. Perhaps building a log table to register the messages can be considered more prudent due to user variable's values constant changing for multi-row insert?

Comment: @blabla_bingo, Honestly, if I needed to know exactly which ones were adjusted, I'd adjust the values in client code before inserting them. Then you don't have to remember to check the variable or log table, whichever is used. Then add a CHECK constraint to reject rows that have failed to be adjusted.